# Mongodb shell command not returning accurate "deletedCount" upon succesful completion?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I have a mongoDB instance running with two collections in it.  I'm using the nodejs driver (version 3.2.4).  I am also using mongoose (version 5.5.9) but as I'm messing around and learning, I've been issuing a few commands directly from the mongoDB shell (rather than through node).  My shell version is 4.0.9.  I should note that this occurred when issuing the command from the built-in terminal in vscode.

I used (from the shell):

```js
db.myCollection.deleteMany({ field: 'value' })
```

to delete a few documents I had in the collection. Per the documentation I expected a document with `acknowledged: <boolean>` and `deletedCount: <number>` to be returned pending a successful operation.  I did get a document back that says:

```js
{
  "acknowledged": true,
  "deletedCount": 0
}
```

However, using Robo 3T I can see that the documents I wanted to delete are definitely deleted.  What gives?

UPDATE:
I've tried several things, including inserting documents matching those that I deleted, and then deleting them again, as well as issuing the commands from my standard terminal shell (not the one in vscode).  I am now unable to replicate this issue.  Nothing super important, especially given that I can't replicate it - but I was wondering if I had somehow issued the commands incorrectly or there was some caveat that wasn't documented clearly.

edits: specificity, added versions, update

Comment: As a quick sanity check, have you also done a `db.myCollection.find({ field: 'value' })`? What MongoDB version are you running? Could you try reproducing the problem, i.e. inserting some dummy documents (preferably identical to your original targets) and attempting to delete them again and see if it's a consistent problem?

Comment: @B.Fleming the `db.myCollection.find({ field: 'value' })` is working as expected, and I've inserted several documents and removed them and cannot replicate the issue. I should also mention that I was using the console in vscode. All the same, I got a `deletedCount` of `0` several times when I originally posted this. At this point I cannot replicate the issue and wonder if there was some sort of weird bug. I've tried in my regular terminal and the one in vscode and nothin' doing!

Comment: Is it possible that you inadvertently double-clicked and that the interface didn't prevent this double-click action from occurring? If so, then the first deletion request would've been processed but would no longer be waited on, while the second would be performed directly after the first deletion occurred and would thus result in a `deletedCount` of `0`. I would try playing around with this and see if you can replicate with a double-click.

Comment: I may have misread. I'm uncertain if a double-click event could occur in a VS console. That being said, I would still play around with seeing if there was some kind of duplicate request occurrence as this seems to be the most likely cause of the incident.